# I want to open my admin panel from Prestashop but I get this error: Attempted to call function "simplexml_load_string" from the global namespace

Tags: php, prestashop, vps

I have a vps server from DigitalOcean and then I installed Prestashop. I can open index page but when I want to open my admin panel I take this :

```
UndefinedFunctionException in AdminController.php line 2216:
Attempted to call function "simplexml_load_string" from the global namespace.
in AdminController.php line 2216
at AdminControllerCore->filterTabModuleList() in AdminController.php line 2175
at AdminControllerCore->addToolBarModulesListButton() in AdminController.php line 1630
at AdminControllerCore->initToolbar() in AdminController.php line 2117
at AdminControllerCore->initToolbarFlags() in AdminController.php line 2850
at AdminControllerCore->init() in Controller.php line 186
at ControllerCore->run() in Dispatcher.php line 379
at DispatcherCore->dispatch() in index.php line 95
```

Version information:

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.33
prestashop -v
1.7.2.1
```

I changed admin folder name and I changed AdminDashboardController to

```
public function setMedia($isNewTheme = false)
    {
        parent::setMedia($isNewTheme);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install on your server the php7.1-simplexml module e.g. for Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-simplexml` or for CentOS `sudo yum install php7.1-simplexml`.